# Relationship between spacelike and timelike distances in General Relativity vs. Special Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, causality

In Minkowski spacetime, the distance $d_S$ between two space-like separated events $x$ and $y$ can (up to constant) be given by a distance between the two time-like separated events $z$ and $w$ where $$z \in J^+(x) \cap J^+(y) ,\quad  w \in J^-(x) \cap J^-(y).$$

Is something analogous possible in GR? I.e., can the distance $d_S$ between two space-like separated events $x$ and $y$ be (up to constant) given by a distance between the two time-like separated events? (I am aware of that the future nor past light cones of two events do not always intersect in general relativistic spacetimes --- see [this previous post here on SE by someone else]([In a globally-hyperbolic spacetime, does every pair of elements have overlapping light cones?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/422423/).

Comment: What do you mean by "is something analogous possible in GR"? Lightcones intersecting is a general feature that extends into curved spacetime but they may not always overlap; I am not sure what your question precisely asks.

Comment: Werner You could correct your hyperlink. The proper syntax is $[...](...)$.

Comment: Are you asking if the spacelike separation of two events be given by the timelike separation of two other events? That is possible trivially, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method to do this in special relativity is essentially the radar synchronization trick : the points $x$ and $y$ are being measured by some observer along the line $\overline{zw}$, such that it emits a light signal at $z$ towards $x$ and $y$ and they are sent back at $w$. Using this and Einstein synchronization, we can get back a distance between the two points.

A first issue here is that the intersections $J^+(x) \cap J^+(y)$ and $J^-(x) \cap J^-(y)$ are not a single point, but define some conics. Presumably here we are meant to take the two points of those conics which are the closest together, as this is something that can be done in Minkowski space.

In the general relativistic case, we can attempt the same process[[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.0170). The first obvious caveat is that there may not exist two points $z,w$ which are at the intersections of the past and future light cones of $x$ and $y$, as the two points may be separated by a horizon. A simple example of this is to pick $y$ outside of the cosmological horizon of $x$ in some FRW spacetime.

Another issue is that in GR, the points $x, y$ may fail to be unique in various ways, giving you a lack of well-defined result. The worst case scenario would be something like a totally vicious spacetime with closed timelike curves through every point, such that $J^\pm(x) = J^\pm(y) = M$, the entire spacetime. Even if your spacetime is globally hyperbolic, there are still circumstances where it may fail to be unique, such as gravitational lensing phenomenon[[2]](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/13/3/016). I'm also not entirely sure that in general you can use the same process to select a unique point in each light cone intersection to get the shortest one, although presumably this isn't important since we only want the distance to be unique, regardless of the points $z$ and $w$.

If we reduce the region we consider to some small enough neighbourhood (called the radar neighbourhood) that is locally Minkowski (and we only consider light rays entirely contained within that neighbourhood), we can indeed always define such a function. We can find two points that are intersections of $J^+(x)$ and $J^+(y)$ and the past light cone as well, define from this an observer (it is the unique timelike geodesic connecting $z$ and $w$), and then define the radar coordinates of that observer, in which case the distance $xy$ is the distance in the foliation defined by those coordinates.

If you can find more than one possible distance due to having multiple possible points $z,w$, it may still be possible to define such a distance by simply picking the shortest possible one, assuming that there is such a thing if the spacetime is well-behaved enough.

Comment: Thanks, @Slereah; this is quite helpful. What I am still wondering about though is whether --- in cases where this construction is well-defined --- the timelike distance given between $z$ and $w$ is indeed numerically the same as the spatial distance (up to the speed of light) between $x$ and $y$, i.e., $d_S$.

Comment: As this is GR there is no unique spacelike distance between two points, this only defines some spacelike foliation which gives you one notion of distance, but it is not unique.

Comment: Thanks, very much, @Slereah. But why is the apparent non-uniqueness a problem? I mean: could the distance between two events x and y that are spacelike distant not be uniquely defined in terms of the length of that connecting geodesic between x and y which is maximal? (In the timelike case, where x and y are timelike, there is only a unique timelike distance because one takes the distance to be the length of the timelike geodesic that is maximal.)

Answer (score 1):

> *In Minkowski spacetime, the distance $d_S$ between two space-like separated events $x$ and $y$ [...]*

"[Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition)" $d_S$ ??

Perhaps you mean the (spatial) separation between two (space-like) separated events $x$ and $y$ in Minkowski spacetime: $$ \text{Sgn}[ \, s^2[ \, x, y \, ] \, ] \, \sqrt{ s^2[ \, x, y \, ] \, \text{Sgn}[ \, s^2[ \, x, y \, ] \, ] }, $$
where $s^2[ \, x, y \, ] = s^2[ \, y, x \, ]$ denotes the spacetime interval value of event pair $(x, y)$.

Distances are instead attributed to pairs of members of an inertial frame.

> *can (up to constant) be given by a distance*

... temporal separation (?) ...

> *between the two time-like separated events $z$ and $w$ where [...]*

Well, if the obvious light-like separations are required $$ s^2[ \, x, w \, ] = s^2[ \, x, z \, ] = s^2[ \, y, w \, ] = s^2[ \, y, z \, ] = 0, $$

and if all four events are required to be [planar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant#Plane) wrt. each other, i.e.

$$ 0 = \text{Det} \begin{bmatrix} 
       0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
       1 & 0 & s^2[ \, w, x \, ] & s^2[ \, w, y \, ] & s^2[ \, w, z \, ] \\
       1 & s^2[ \, x, w \, ] & 0 & s^2[ \, x, y \, ] & s^2[ \, x, z \, ] \\
       1 & s^2[ \, y, w \, ] & s^2[ \, y, x \, ] & 0 & s^2[ \, y, z \, ] \\
       1 & s^2[ \, z, w \, ] & s^2[ \, z, x \, ] & s^2[ \, z, y \, ] & 0 
\end{bmatrix} $$

so together:

$$ 0 = \text{Det} \begin{bmatrix} 
       0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
       1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & s^2[ \, w, z \, ] \\
       1 & 0 & 0 & s^2[ \, x, y \, ] & 0 \\
       1 & 0 & s^2[ \, y, x \, ] & 0 & 0 \\
       1 & s^2[ \, z, w \, ] & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}, $$

therefore $s^2[ \, x, y \, ] = -s^2[ \, w, z \, ]$.

> *Is something analogous possible in GR?*

In GR "we have" (in a manner of speaking) values $\ell$ of [(asymmetric) Lorentzian distance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Lorentzian+distance%22) for each pair of events (with non-zero values for pairs of time-like separated events; depending on the order of arguments).

Then it seems straightforward to define e.g.

$$ \chi[ \, x, y \, ] := \begin{cases} \ell[ \, x, y \, ] & \text{ if } \ell[ \, x, y \, ] \ne 0, \\ \ell[ \, y, x \, ] & \text{ if } \ell[ \, y, x \, ] \ne 0, \\ (-) \underset{ \ell[ \, w, x \, ] \ne 0, \, \ell[ \, w, y \, ] \ne 0, \, \ell[ \, x, z \, ] \ne 0, \, \ell[ \, y, z \, ] \ne 0 }{\text{Inf}}[ \, \{ \ell[ \, w, z \, ] \} \, ] & \text{ otherwise.} \end{cases} $$

But it'd seem a more ambitious project to define some quantity with generally non-zero values for space-like separated event pairs such that they are **compatible to** values of [Synge's world function $\sigma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synge%27s_world_function) (if such values are defined for the event pairs under consideration); i.e. such that

$$ \chi_{\text{comp}}[ \, x, y \, ] := \text{Sgn}[ \, \sigma[ \, x, y \, ] \, ] \, \sqrt{ 2 \, \sigma[ \, x, y \, ] \, \text{Sgn}[ \, \sigma[ \, x, y \, ] \, ] } $$

for each pair $(x, y)$ for which a value $\sigma[ \, x, y \, ]$ is "given".